# azure compute emulator not starting since addition of https endpoint

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate

I'm at a loss, and have not found answers within existing questions or elsewhere on google, so any help is greatly appreciated.

On my windows azure site I recently added an SSL cert and https endpoints.  I've uploaded to azure, and it's working fine there, but now on my development machine I get an error each time I try to start the roles, saying "role instances are taking longer than expected to start"..... and no matter how long I wait, they won't start.  If I comment out the HttpsIn binding and InputEndpoint, I have no issue locally.

csdef file:

```
    <Certificates>
  <Certificate name="EMSFleet" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
</Certificates>
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="EMSFleet" />
</Endpoints>
```

cscfg local file

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="EMSFleet" thumbprint="xxx" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1"/>
 <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption"    thumbprint="xxx" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you very much.  Mark

Comment: What happens when you change the storeName to `My` instead of `CA`?

Comment: Tried that, no difference

Comment: Have you installed this certificate in your local computer's certificate store?

Comment: I think so.  I created the certificate on my dev machine using DigiCert - It looks to me like the certificate is in there.  I'm new to SSL certificates, so I followed the instructions here and on the azure site - I didn't see anything about needing to upload it separately to the emulator given that it was created on the same machine.  Did I miss a step there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Solution found.  I was running IISExpress, I installed IIS 7 (control panel - programs - turn on/off window features) and now it works just fine.  It definitely appears to be an issue with IIS express not running properly with the SSL certificates.

More info here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/ad362016-16f6-459a-8022-9307aa5f910e/visual-studio-hangs-at-starting-the-roles-for-the-application-in-the-windows-azure-compute?forum=windowsazuredevelopment